# Change the height of the row instead of the column width

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have created a table using React and Tailwind CSS. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Table = () => {
    return (
        <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>
            <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2'>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2'>surname</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {current.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.first_name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.last_name}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Pagination className="mt-2 pb-20" dir='ltr' page={currentPage} count={pageCount} onChange={handleChange} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

My problem is that when the length of an entry is more than the default column width, that column becomes wider and the other column shrinks accordingly. All I want is that when the length of an entry is more than the default column width, instead of making the column wider, the height of the corresponding row changes and the extra part of the entry moves to the next row. I mean instead of this:

```
name           surname
------------   -------
samsamsammmm   Brown
------------   -------
```

I want this:

```
name      surname
-------   -------
samsam    Brown
sammmm
-------   -------
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

in the css for the coresponding element add

```
 white-space: pre-line !important;
```

or try diffent ones https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

and optionaly add max width for the parent to not be wider than the window's width no matter how much you shrink

```
table {
   max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Tailwind CSS. Where should I put this piece of code? in the table header or rows? I tried both of them but it didn't work for me.

Comment: give th,td {max-width: 100px} or whatever width you want (%, vw)